# Reorder one nested list to match another

Tags: geometry

I have a nested list:
coords = [[4, 4], [5, 4], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [5, 6], [4, 6], [4, 5]]

After applying a process to this list one of the items is changed (for example (6, 6) ---> (7, 6))
However in the process the order of the items has shifted and creates a new list (cstates)

cstates = [[4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 4], [5, 6], [6, 4], [6, 5], [7, 6]]

Is it possible to reorder cstates such that it matches the order of coords and the item which was changed is inserted into the remaining position?

Ps the order important as it draws out a shape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euNle.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxdkh.png)

I was hoping there was a predefined function that could do this, rather than having to iterate through each item

Answer (score 0):

You can store additional item - index in initial list, and after transformation restore order using sort by this parameter

```
[[4, 4, 0], [5, 4, 1], [6, 4, 2], ...
```

Comment: Ahh you're a legend, alright this was a good idea, i'll try it